# Windows Phone 8 game development

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm installing the SDK for WP8 now and have a few questions. XNA seems to be supported but only in a legacy mode. So for game stuff I assume you have a choice of XAML based,... what, is it Silverlight still? And if the game is 3D or graphically intensive then it's C++ and Direct X?

Is there an option of C# with managed Direct X for gaming in there?

Or some XAML + DirectX mix?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an option of C# with managed Direct X for gaming in there?

No. *(Or well, [SharpDX](http://www.sharpdx.org/news/new-version-2-4-0) is now available for WP8)*

> Or some XAML + DirectX mix?

You wouldn't want to go down that path. Stick to DirectX and C++ if you want to create a game. Silverlight forces 60 FPS which is horrendous for battery life, and makes the devices incredible hot if used for rendering games or video.

Comment: Excellent info, thanks. It's frustrating though, I'd have liked a managed option that wasn't a kludge :/

Comment: If you want a 2d game on wp8 you are kind of out of luck. Direct2D is not supported....